# Django: phone verification for inactive account

Tags: python, django, authorization, verification

I'd like to implement phone verification with `pyotp` in my view class-based Django (2.5) project.

After new users sign up (specifying name, phone, e-mail and password) in `RegisterView`, they should be redirected to `GetAccessCodeView` with an input field for verification code and a hidden field with a secure token. For generating and sending the code and the token I have to pass there a newly created user instanse from `RegisterView` to `GetAccessCodeView`.

How can I do that? Currently newly created users have `is_active` field set to `False` (it should become `True` after code succesful verification), thus cannot be authorized by default, so without changing login procedure, it is impossible to use `request.user` directly. But if I let inactive users to log in, then all the `login_required` views will let unconfirmed users to open corresponding pages. Should I write `is_active` check for each view manually or maybe Django has some ready stuff like 'login_and_active_required'? Or maybe there is some different solution?

Comment: You could simply save the id of the freshly-registered user in an *anonymous session*. You don't need to *log in* the user to have a session.